# Finding $1$-periodic $h_{\omega}(s)$'s so that $\lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s) = s$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

One can show that the expression
$$ \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} $$
approaches $s$ as $\omega\rightarrow 0$ by L'Hopital's rule.

However, it seems there is no convergence when considering $\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n$ and $n$ is a nonzero integer (unless we plug special values of $s$).

My question is, are there **$1$-periodic functions** $h_{\omega}(s)$ such that
$$ \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n}\frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s) = s $$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? At the very least, can we find something that works for at least $n=1$? The functions $h_{\omega}(s)$ should be $1$-periodic in $s$ for every $\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit relation holds for $s$ and $s + 1$ then taking the difference we get
$$
\lim_{w\to2\pi n}\left[\frac{e^{-iws} - 1}{e^{-iw} - 1} + h_w(s) - \frac{e^{-iw(s + 1)} - 1}{e^{-iw} - 1} - h_w(s + 1)\right] = -1.
$$
If $h_w$ is $1$-periodic then $h_w(s)$ and $h_w(s + 1)$ cancel out, giving
\begin{gather*}
-1 = \lim_{w\to2\pi n}\left[\frac{e^{-iws} - 1}{e^{-iw} - 1} - \frac{e^{-iw(s + 1)} - 1}{e^{-iw} - 1} \right] 
= \lim_{w\to2\pi n}\left[\frac{e^{-iws} - e^{-iw(s + 1)}}{e^{-iw} - 1} \right] 
\\
= \lim_{w\to2\pi n}\left[\frac{e^{-iws}(1 - e^{-iw} )}{e^{-iw} - 1} \right] = -e^{-i2\pi ns},
\end{gather*}
which does not hold for noninteger $s$ if $n\neq 0$.