# Follow-up: $h_{\omega}(s)$'s so that $\lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s) = e^{-i2\pi n s}s$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

This is a follow-up question or variant question to [Finding $1$-periodic $h_{\omega}(s)$'s so that $\lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s) = s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873818/finding-1-periodic-h-omegass-so-that-lim-omega-rightarrow-2-pi-n).

Let $n$ be a nonzero integer. I am wondering now if it is possible to find $1$-periodic functions $h_{\omega}(s)$ such that

$$ \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n}\frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s) = a_{n}(s) + b_{n}(s)s $$

where $a_{n}, b_{n}$ are themselves $1$-periodic functions. We can remove the need for $a_{n}$ by plugging $h_{\omega}(s) = h'_{\omega}(s) + a_{n}(s)$ for all $\omega$. Then we can deduce

\begin{align*}
b_{n}(s) &= b_{n}(s+1)(s+1) - b_{n}(s)s \\
&= \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega (s+1)} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s+1) - \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} - h_{\omega}(s) \\
&= \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega (s+1)} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} - \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} \\
&= \cdots = e^{-i2\pi n s},
\end{align*}

so my question is reduces to the following:

**Question.** Given a nonzero integer $n$, is it possible to find $1$-periodic functions $h_{\omega}(s)$ such that

$$ \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n}\frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + h_{\omega}(s) = e^{-i 2\pi n s}s? $$

(Apologies if this question is too similar to the previous one. I think this post is sufficiently different/interesting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us consider the problem for a fixed nonzero integer $n$. We propose
$$ h_{\omega}(s) = \frac{1-e^{-2\pi i n s}}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} $$
for $\omega\in (2\pi n - \pi, 2\pi n + \pi)\setminus\{2\pi n\}$,
which satisfies $h_{\omega}(s+1) = h_{\omega}(s)$. We have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + \frac{1-e^{-2\pi i n s}}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} &= \lim_{\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n} \frac{e^{-i\omega s} - e^{-2\pi i n s}}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} \\[1.0ex]
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{-i(2\pi n + \varepsilon) s} - e^{-2\pi i n s}}{e^{-i(2\pi n + \varepsilon)} - 1} \\[1.0ex]
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} e^{-2\pi i n s}\frac{e^{-i\varepsilon s} - 1}{e^{-i\varepsilon} - 1} \\[1.0ex]
&= e^{-2\pi i n s}\frac{-is}{-i} \\[1.0ex]
&= e^{-2\pi i n s}s.
\end{align*}

For a solution that works for all integers $n$, define
$$ h_{\omega}(s) = \frac{1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} + \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-e^{-2\pi i k s}}{e^{-i\omega} - 1}\psi_{k}(\omega) $$
for all $\omega\not\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, where the $\psi_{k}$'s come from any choice of functions such that for each $k$ we have (i) $\psi_{k}(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega\not\in(2\pi k-\pi, 2\pi k+\pi)$ and (ii) $\psi_{k}(\omega) = 1$ on some neighborhood $U\ni\omega$. The choice of $\psi_{k}$'s can be smooth bump functions or more simply we can just set $\psi_{k}(\omega) = 1$ for $2\pi k-\pi < \omega < 2\pi k + \pi$ and $0$ otherwise.

At any $\omega\not\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, the expression for $h_{\omega}$ will consist of at most two nonzero terms, which are determined by which value of $2\pi n$ is $\omega$ closest to.

---

### Extra Findings

I thought I would also share a solution in which the summation in the expression for $h_{\omega}$ is evaluated and thus doesn't need to appear in the final expression. The functions $\psi_{k}(\omega)$ don't have to be the way I described them, so long as they converge $\psi_{k}(\omega)\rightarrow \delta_{nk}$ "sufficiently fast" as $\omega\rightarrow 2\pi n$.

So for example, let $\psi_{k}(\omega) = \text{sinc}^{2}(\omega - 2\pi k)$. The solution is then

\begin{align*}
h_{\omega}(s) &= \frac{1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1} - \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2\pi i ks}}{e^{-i\omega} - 1}\text{sinc}^{2}\left(\omega - 2\pi k\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1}\left( 1 - \sin^{2}\omega \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2\pi i ks}}{(\omega - 2\pi k)^{2}} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1}\left( 1 - \sin^{2}\omega\; e^{-i\omega \{s\}}e^{i\omega/2}\frac{(2\{s\}-1)i\sin(\tfrac{\omega}{2}) + \cos(\tfrac{\omega}{2})}{4\sin^{2}\frac{\omega}{2}}  \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{e^{-i\omega} - 1}\left( 1 - e^{-i\omega\{s\}}\cos^{2}(\tfrac{\omega}{2}) (1 - \{s\} + e^{i\omega}\{s\}) \right) 
\end{align*}
where $\{s\} = s-\lfloor s\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $s$. Going from the second line to the third is done by evaluating the sum. Going from the third line to the fourth is a matter of rewriting and simplifying the RHS expression. The reader can check that the last expression for $h_{\omega}$ satisfies all the requirements for problem posed in the OP.

To evaluate the summation, I took an approach analogous to [this one in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/379280). Consider the function $F(z) = e^{iz(s-1/2)}/((z+\omega)^{2}\sin(z/2))$, take the contour integral over the circle of radius $R$ around $z=0$, apply the residue theorem, and send $R\rightarrow\infty$. The integral goes to zero as $R\rightarrow\infty$ only for $0 < s < 1$, so the method only works for $s\in (0, 1)$. However, our sum is $1$-periodic in $s$, so we can extend our result by replacing $s$'s with their fractional parts.